# Proof that there is no infinite arithmetic sequence where each term is distinct and is the reciprocal of an integer

Tags: sequences-and-series

How does one prove that there is no infinite arithmetic sequence where each term is distinct and is the reciprocal of an integer?

Comment: If the sequence is increasing, then eventually .... If the sequence is decreasing, then eventually ....

Comment: eventually what??

Comment: C'mon, Kite – think about it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\{a+kd\} $ be an arithmetic sequence.

Let $\frac 1 {a+kd}=n$ be an integer.  Then $a+kd = 1/n $.

So $-1\le a+kd \le 1$ and $-a-1\le kd \le -a+1$ and $\frac {-a-1}k \le d \le \frac {-a+1}k $.

The only way this can be true for *all* $k $ is if $d=0$ because for arbitrarily large $k $ then $\frac {-a-1}k$ and  $\frac {-a+1}k $ can be arbitrarily small.

So only if the the terms are equal ($d=0$) is it possible for all terms to be the reciprical of integers.

In other words, *eventually* a term will be greater than 1 or less than negative one.  Or both.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Reciprocals of integers are numbers between 0 and 1. Arithmetic sequence can be increasing or decreasing. If it is increasing what will eventually happen? If it is decreasing?

Comment: (Hint: What does the nth term of such a sequence look like if 1/x1 and 1/x2 are the first and second terms of the sequence respectively for non-zero integers x1 and x2)??

Comment: That is another approach. Using first two terms you can find common difference $d$ and then write the formula for the nth term or arithmetic sequence $a_n=a_1+(n-1)d$ and conclude that the sequence is not arithmetic.

Comment: then how to proof

Comment: Once you obtain formula for the nth term, you can easily conclude that not all elements of sequence are reciprocals of integers. Formula for $a_n$ can be easily obtained using definition of arithmetic sequence, and I want you to do that part on your own.

Comment: <3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3 Thanks

Comment: But consider solving the problem the way i gave you a hint. It is easier than handling all those fractions. All reciprocals of integers are between 0 and 1 and arithmetic sequence does not have limit, so eventually terms of arithmetic sequence will obtain values outside $(0,1]$.